# Is the rfacebookstat package secure?

Tags: r, api, security, oauth, facebook-marketing-api

Full disclaimer - I'm a bit of an API noob and I don't have much experience with OAuth or token authorization in general.

I see that the `rfacebookstat` package is on [CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rfacebookstat/index.html) but I'm in particular concerned about the following [function:](https://github.com/cran/rfacebookstat/blob/master/R/authorization.R)

```
  function(
    app_id = NULL,
    scopes = c("ads_read", "business_management", "pages_manage_ads", "ads_management", "public_profile") ){
    if(is.null(app_id)) stop("Enter your app id.")
    scopes <- paste(scopes, collapse = ",")
    utils::browseURL(paste0("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=",app_id  ,"&display=popup&redirect_uri=https://selesnow.github.io/rfacebookstat/getToken/get_token.html&response_type=token&scope=",scopes))
    token <- readline(prompt = "Enter your token: ")
    options(rfacebookstat.access_token = token)
    return(token)
}
```

I see there's a redirect to the package creator's **personal github site** and that makes me a bit nervous. From the .R file I see that this is needed in order to convert the short time token into a long time token - does this represent a security concern? Anyone else have experience with this package? Want to use but I also don't want to leak any campaign data externally.

Alternatively, if I were to write my own wrapper of the above function, could I use localhost as the redirect URI? I just need to query the API to pull historical campaign data, the script I'm writing isn't for any webapp.

Comment: I don't think you can easily come up with a localhost variant, since that would require that `facebook.com` would be able to get to your localhost on some port (e.g., 80 or 443), which _should_ require explicit firewall/router configuration to allow. But if you can arrange it, I suggest you submit a PR to the author. (I'm _guessing_ that that is why the author has set up that page, in order to facilitate something he knows most users will not be able to do due to firewalls/routers. I think your concern is valid, perhaps the author should be more transparent on it.)

Comment: It does not help English-speakers that the redirect site is in Russian; disregarding current world events, just that alone can be cause for concern. I'm not trying to incite anything, and it is likely that most Russian-speaking programmers are "good people", but there has been cause for concern in the past with `.ru` domains, and current world events can put more people on edge. (Disclaimer: without wanting a flame-war, *I support Ukraine*.)